# How to use 主持 in composition

Tags: meaning, usage

I know the basic meaning of 主持， which is "taking charge of". But I don't know how and on what occasion I can use this word.

Can I just use this for all the things which someone is responsible for?

Like:

```
主持会议，
主持单位，
主持家务，
主持工作，
主持推销
```

Comment: Better to use 主管单位, 主管推销.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there's a site written by Chinese explained the meaning of "主持". And here it is: http://baike.baidu.com/subview/77617/14131395.htm

Then, there are some points I think I should explain for you:

```
1. When it comes to Ancient Chinese, the "主持" always means someone handles or deal with things. And at this time, it's a verb. But when we visit a temple, we would call the head-hander "主持" -- now it's a noun.

2. When it comes to Modern Chinese, this word means someone in charge of some things, especially something matters or grand to cater for the solemn atmosphere there. In those occasions you can use it, and others will not feel you choose your words unexpected.
```

Hope can help :)

Answer (score 1):

主持 have several different meanings. "In charge of something" is one of them but it is usage is rather limited, you can say 主持家务 主持工作 but that's about it in this sense of the word. Think of the above two as fixed phrases. You dont want to use "主持" anytime you want to express the meaning of "in change of", "主管" is probably more often used word. 
The word "主持” more often takes on the meaning of 'host' and 'moderate'

主持晚会 host a gala
主持会议 moderate a meeting

Answer (score 0):

as the phases you listed, 主持 is a verb, meaning as presiding, leading, directing, or mastering. That is, acting as the commander of organization, or a task.

Also, a joke for you .... 主持 (or 住持) could also be a noun, which is the head of monks in a temple :)